# Pandas str.contains returned false positives

Tags: python, pandas

I am aggregating based on whether a column value contains "`Done`" or "`Tied Done`". This month I received an additional string "`Done Cancel`" which is getting incorrectly aggregated. So `str.contains` is not appropriate anymore. What alternative can be used to sum based on explicit strings?

```
aggregate = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'), ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.str.contains('Done').sum())]
dfProduct_Hit_Rate = dfAPAC_Bus_Mngr.groupby(['rbc_security_type1'])['state'].agg(aggregate).reset_index()
```

Is replacing `str.contains` with `str.match` the ideal solution here? i.e.
`('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.str.match('Done','Tied Done').sum())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `==` operator or [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html), which requires exact matches:

```
aggregate = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'),
             ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.eq('Done').sum())]
```

If you wish to include multiple strings, use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
aggregate = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'),
             ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.isin(['Done', 'Tied Done']).sum())]
```

If you need to *exclude* a single string while including all others with `'Done'`, combine conditions via bitwise "and" operator `&`. For example, with `!=` or [`pd.Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
aggregate = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'),
             ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: ((x.str.contains('Done') & (x.ne('Done Cancel')).sum())]
```

Comment: Hi @jpp.but this will not inclued Tied Done which is a valid value.I need to sum if it's Done or Tied DOne but not Cancel Done